# How to display sliding up panel expanded?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using umano's [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). I want to display the sliding panel as expanded. Following is my fragment code.

```
public class Anasayfa extends BaseFragment {
    private SlidingUpPanelLayout partViewer;

    public Anasayfa(String id, String title) {
        super(id,title);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        partViewer = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_issue_part, container, false);

        Issue issue = TaskManager.getIssue(TaskManager.getLatestIssueDate(),getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        IssuePageAdapter adapter = new IssuePageAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), issue.getPartAnaGazete());

        ViewPager issuePager = (ViewPager) partViewer.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        issuePager.setAdapter(adapter);

        partViewer.expandPanel();

        return partViewer;
    }
}
```

I attach the fragment into my activity using following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    settings = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", 0);

    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(this);

    setupDrawer();

    gotoFragmentAnasayfa();
}

public void gotoFragmentAnasayfa() {
    Fragment myApp = new Anasayfa("", "Anasayfa");
    goToFragment(myApp);
}

private void goToFragment(Fragment view) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, view);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

But I get NullPointerException since `SlidingUpPanelLayout.mSlideableView` has not been instantiated.

Following is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.promob.myapp/com.promob.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.expandPanel(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:887)
        at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.expandPanel(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:876)
        at com.promob.myapp.fragment.Anasayfa.onCreateView(Anasayfa.java:39)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
```

`mSlideableView` is instantiated within `SlidingUpPanelLayout.onMeasure()` method (See line 574 on [SlidingUpPanelLayout.java](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java)).

How (or in which lifecycle phase) should I display sliding up panel expanded?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please also provide stacktrace

Comment: I suppose the problem is that you only created the view, but it is not added to the screen, so the onMeasure was never called. You should attach view to the screen and then call expand

Comment: Ok, I have put stack trace and additional details @SemyonDanilov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salaam.

In latest version I use, this attribute was added:

```
sothree:umanoInitialState="expanded"
```

so my code like this:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/spl_SlideLayout_activity_searchform"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView" 

    sothree:umanoInitialState="expanded" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
1) Send message to activity's handler and then open the panel:

in onCreateView:

```
partViewer = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_issue_part, container, false);
Handler h = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        partViewer.expandPanel();
    }
}
h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
...
```

I don't prefer this solution, because it seems to be a bug in the library, so:

2) Rewrite the SlideUpPanel class and define mSlideableView in constructor just like it does in onMeasure.

Comment: **Option 1:** didn't work. I got the same error and the same stack trace.


**Option 2:** didn't work. I put `mSlideableView = getChildAt(1)` inside constructor. But at the time of constructor execution `getChildAt(1)` returns null, since view layout has not been completed yet.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/SammyVimes/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java
I made some changes in SlidingUpPanel code and now you can open panel anywhere